# Как получить данные об успешной отправке формы?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Имеется форма добавления информации в базу данных.

После отправки страница перезагружается.

Как получить данные об успешной отправке формы и error?

Страницу обновлять по любому нужно, так как обновляется список на странице.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["email"])) {       
    $db->query( "INSERT INTO `d_users` ( email, ... ) VALUES ('{$_POST['email']}', ..." );
}
?>


<form class="col s12" action="" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input name="email" placeholder="00000" id="email" type="text" value="">
            <label for="email">email:</label>
        </div>
        ...     
    </div>
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="добавить"></td>
</form>
```

Comment: Как на счет отправлять данные в базу через AJAX технологию? А по успешному виполнению, обновлять данные строк, как результат выполнения действий.

Comment: Я полностью ЗА, только не умею

Comment: Самое время научиться, а мы поможем, чем сможем. Посмотрите [fetch](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch) или [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Comment: Пора бы уже забыть про jquery, 23 год за окном.

Comment: @Elmir а что вы предлагаете в замен использовать? TypeScript ? или вам нравится писать document.getElementById() и другие конструкции по работе с DOM ?

Comment: @Elmir а что внезапно с jquery случилось? И нам расскажите, интересно же

Comment: @Mcile а TypeScript тут при чем?)

Comment: @Mcile Да мне нравится. Мне нравится querySelector, мне нравится fetch, axios. TypeScript мне тоже нравится.

Comment: @Elmir мы очень за вас рады (sarcasm), вот только не нужно свои идеи по типу "ты че совсем что ли? какой jquery? на дворе 2023 год" навязывать другим

Comment: @SemyonBayandin больше всего конечно power point нравится

Comment: @Elmir а вы прям мастер троллинга. Где учились?